# Функция вылетает посередине исполнения, возвращая None Python 3

Tags: python-3.x

Я написал рекурсивную функцию, для решения задачи.

```
def f(bool_table, current_x, current_y, cl):
global word
global table
if cl == len(word) - 1:
    return True

if bool_table[current_x + 1][current_y]:
    if table[current_x + 1][current_y] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x + 1][current_y] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x + 1, current_y, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x - 1][current_y]:
    if table[current_x - 1][current_y] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x - 1][current_y] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x - 1, current_y, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x][current_y + 1]:
    if table[current_x][current_y + 1] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x][current_y + 1] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x, current_y + 1, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x][current_y - 1]:
    if table[current_x][current_y - 1] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x][current_y - 1] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x, current_y - 1, cl + 1):
            return True

else:
    return False
```

Когда я запускаю её `e = f(bool_table, i, j, 1)` и дебагаю, она проходит первый if, затем заходит на if, который находится в нём, после чего возвращается на строку вызова, возвращая None (после этого e = None)

Почему она вообще что-то возвращает на этом этапе исполнения? Как пофиксить этот вылет и сделать функцию рабочей?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У Вас при `False` любого из вложенных `if` функция возвращает `None`, так как не попадает на команду `return`. А при отсутствии `return` возвращаемое значение функции `None` - по умолчанию.

Так как назначение Вашей функции неизвестно, то единственное, что могу посоветовать - убрать `else` перед `return False`:

```
def f(bool_table, current_x, current_y, cl):
global word
global table
if cl == len(word) - 1:
    return True

if bool_table[current_x + 1][current_y]:
    if table[current_x + 1][current_y] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x + 1][current_y] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x + 1, current_y, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x - 1][current_y]:
    if table[current_x - 1][current_y] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x - 1][current_y] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x - 1, current_y, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x][current_y + 1]:
    if table[current_x][current_y + 1] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x][current_y + 1] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x, current_y + 1, cl + 1):
            return True

elif bool_table[current_x][current_y - 1]:
    if table[current_x][current_y - 1] == word[cl]:
        bool_table[current_x][current_y - 1] = False
        if f(bool_table, current_x, current_y - 1, cl + 1):
            return True

return False
```

Comment: А заодно ещё и все elif на if заменить, спасибо.

Comment: @lesstrq, И это тоже возможно. Когда исправляю чей-то код, я всегда стараюсь обходиться минимумом правок. И, кстати, если мой ответ Вам помог, отметьте его, пожалуйста, как принятый, кликнув на `v` под количеством голосов.